# My continuation task appears to be complete before it finishes running

Tags: task, task-parallel-library, continuations

I have a non-intuitive issue with a continuation task that I would think task.Wait would wait for the continuation task but it yields `RanToCompletion` before the task even finishes running? Here is the short source code. The output is below:

```cs
private static void TestChildTasks()
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() => RunParentTask());
    Task t2 = t.ContinueWith(task => Task.Run(() => RunChildTask()));
    //Task t2 = Task.Run(() => RunChildTask());
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting on t1");
    t.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Done waiting on t1");

    Console.WriteLine($"Waiting on t2, status of {t2.Status}");
    t2.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine($"Finished; child task is {t2.Status}");
}

private static void RunParentTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parent Task is running");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Parent Task is done");
}

private static void RunChildTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Child task is running");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("Child Task is done");
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Waiting on t1

Parent Task is running

Parent Task is done

Done waiting on t1

Waiting on t2, status of Running

Finished; child task is RanToCompletion

press enter to exit

Child task is running

Child Task is done
```

Why does the child task continue to run after it returns a status of `RanToCompletion`?

Comment: There are two "child" tasks. The first is called by `ContinueWith` and starts a new task that runs the method `RunChildTask`. That third task is never awaited. Why write such code anyway, instead of using `await` ?

Comment: @QFury With `Task.Run` inside your `ContinueWith` you basically fire and forget the child task. That's why it's completed right after the `t` has completed and called its continuation.

Comment: @QFury if you change your `t2` definition to this: `Task t2 = t.ContinueWith(_ => RunChildTask());` then it would not run after `t2.Wait()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the following line:

```cs
Task t2 = t.ContinueWith(task => Task.Run(() => RunChildTask()));
```

Even though you have declared `t2` as `Task` it is really a `Task<Task>`:

```cs
Task<Task> t2 = t.ContinueWith(task => Task.Run(() => RunChildTask()));
```

Why? Because `Task.Run` creates a new `Task`.

You have several options to fix this:

#### Option #1 - Unwrap

To make a `Task` from a `Task<Task>` you need to call the `Unwrap` method.

```cs
Task t2 = t.ContinueWith(task => Task.Run(() => RunChildTask())).Unwrap();
```

With this modification the output will look like this:

```
Waiting on t1
Parent Task is running
Parent Task is done
Done waiting on t1
Child task is running
Waiting on t2, status of WaitingForActivation
Child Task is done
Finished; child task is RanToCompletion
```

#### Option #2 - Avoid new task creation

Actually you can call the `RunChildTask` without the `Task.Run`:

```cs
Task t2 = t.ContinueWith(_ => RunChildTask());
```

With this modification the output will look like this:

```
Waiting on t1
Parent Task is running
Parent Task is done
Done waiting on t1
Child task is running
Waiting on t2, status of Running
Child Task is done
Finished; child task is RanToCompletion
```

#### Option #3 - AttachToParent

If you want to you can attach a Task not just with the `ContinueWith`, but also with the `Task.Factory.StartNew`:

```cs
Task t2 = null;
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    RunParentTask();
    t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(RunChildTask, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
});
```

With this modification the output will look like this:

```
Waiting on t1
Parent Task is running
Parent Task is done
Child task is running
Child Task is done
Done waiting on t1
Waiting on t2, status of RanToCompletion
Finished; child task is RanToCompletion
```

There are several other ways as well.

Comment: I can't upvote you (I don't have enough "reputation" points), but thank you!

Comment: @QFury If you think that this does answer your question then you can mark it as the answer. If you need further information then please feel free to ask in the comments.